# Engine oil change interval difference

Tags: honda, oil, scooter, hero-honda

I know of 2 fully automatic scooters(Honda activa and Hero Pleasure) produced by 2 different manufacturers which use exactly the same engine produced by honda but their recommended oil grade and oil change interval is different.What could be the reason for this.?

[EDIT]
Just found service manual of an older model(2009) of Honda Activa.Here the recommended oil grade is 20w40 and change interval of 6000 kms and top up every 3000kms.Newer model has recommended 10w30 with oil change every 4000kms.There is no change in the displacement of the older vs newer model.Is it just for making more money with frequent oil changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stick to Honda corp. For their standards, they know their engines well. Besides Hero and Honda had a combined venture until 2015.

Answer (score 1):

One reason can be marketing, to appeal potential buyers with extended engine oil change intervals.